# SARIMA explicit formula

Tags: arima, seasonality

I'm trying to expand the $\mathrm{ARIMA}(1,1,2)(1,0,1)[7]$ model to get the explicit formula.

Writing the model with polynomial operators should be

$$
\phi_1(B)\Phi_1(B^7)(1-B) x_t = \theta_2(B) \Theta_1 (B^7) \varepsilon_t
$$

from which we get the process

$$
(1- \phi_1 B)(1 - \Phi_1 B^7)(1 - B) x_t = (1 - \theta_1B - \theta_2B^2)(1 - \Theta_1B^7) \varepsilon_t
$$

that leads to

$$
(-\phi_1\Phi_1B^9 + \phi_1\Phi_1B^8 + \Phi_1B^8 - \Phi_1B^7 + \phi_1B^2 - \phi_1B - B + 1) x_t
\\
=
\\
(\theta_1 \Theta_1 B^8 + \theta_2 \Theta_1 B^9 -
\Theta_1 B^7  - \theta_1 B  - \theta_2 B^2  + 1) \varepsilon_t
$$

Expanding the back-shift operators $B$ we then get

$$
-\phi_1\Phi_1x_{t-9} + \phi_1\Phi_1x_{t-8} + \Phi_1x_{t-8} - \Phi_1x_{t-7} + \phi_1x_{t-2} - \phi_1x_{t-1} - x_{t-1} + x_t
\\
=
\\
\theta_1 \Theta_1 \varepsilon_{t-8} + \theta_2 \Theta_1 \varepsilon_{t-9} -
\Theta_1 \varepsilon_{t-7}  - \theta_1 \varepsilon_{t-1}  - \theta_2 \varepsilon_{t-2}  + \varepsilon_{t}
$$

from which we can finally write

$$
\begin{align*}
x_t  & = x_{t-1} \\
 & + \phi_1 (x_{t-1} - x_{t-2}) \\
 & + \Phi_1 (x_{t-7} -  x_{t-8}) - \Phi_1 \phi_1 (x_{t-8} - x_{t-9}) \\
 & + \varepsilon_{t} - \theta_1 \varepsilon_{t-1} - \theta_2 \varepsilon_{t-2} \\
 & - \Theta_1\varepsilon_{t-7} + \Theta_1 ( \theta_1 \varepsilon_{t-8} + \theta_2 \varepsilon_{t-9})
\end{align*}
$$

where $\varepsilon_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$.

Is that correct?

---

## EDIT

I edited an error. Polynomial operator $\theta_2(B) = 1 - \theta_1B - \theta_2B^2$, I wrote $\theta_2B$ instead.